# How to set protocols to URI's without writing regex

Tags: java

I have an app that takes a user-input URL and fetches it. It must be a valid url with a protocol.
However, the user may forget to include the protocol.

For example, when I go to this site I just type

```
stackoverflow.com
```

Instead of

```
http://stackoverflow.com
```

Because I know my browser will handle it for me anyways (along with auto-complete, so I usually only have to write `stack`)

So I go ahead

```
String lnk = "stackoverflow.com";
try {
  URL url = new URL(lnk);  
} catch (Exception e ) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it throws an exception

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: stackoverflow.com
```

Exploring the `URL` class, there is no `setProtocol` method either, so this might not help.

What should I use if I want to set protocols for input strings that may or may not have a protocol specified? I could do string scanning and checking manually.

Comment: Why the restriction against regex? That seems like a perfectly acceptable tool to detect whether a string already includes a protocol.

Comment: @Alex the restrction is on having regex hardcoded into my own code. I only mentioned regex since that was the suggested solution in several questions I looked at, and it looked more eye-catching.

Comment: Not quite following you - regex capability is built-in to Java, and the pattern for matching the protocol portion of a URL is not going to change, so I don't see any drawbacks to including a regex in your code.

Answer (score 3):

The `URL` class has a constructor that takes a protocol String as input:

```
URL.URL(String protocol, String host, String file)
```

e.g. `URL url = new URL("http", "stackoverflow.com", "");`

If a protocol needs to be added in case it is missing, the below snippet could be used for `http` and `https`:

```
if(!lnk.startsWith("http://") && !lnk.startsWith("https://")) {
    lnk = "http://" + lnk;
}
```

Comment: I like the constructor, but sometimes users just copy-paste addresses from the browser and the `http` will be included in there. So if you said `new URL("http", "http://stackoverflow.com", "");` you get a funny-looking URL with square braces.

Comment: In this case manually adding it is probably the simplest solution. Updated the post to handle `http(s)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could check if it contains http or not using:

```
...
if(!lnk.startsWith("http://") {
   lnk = "http://" + lnk;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you should probably check for `https` too